# Android 2.3 ProgressDialog wont show

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I desperately need help. I've been pulling me hair on this one for awhile. Is there any reason why the `ProgressDialog` wont show up in my app here?

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
    @Override         
    public void onClick(View v) {                
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(AndroidPHPConnection.this, "","Validating user...", true);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {  
            public void run() {                            
                login();                                                 
            }
        }).start();                           
    }        
});
```

Comment: And you're sure that the `onClick` method is being called?

Comment: It seems to be called. The button reacts to the click. However the contents within onClick seem to do nothing.

Comment: If your `login()` method is not being called, then the thread is not being started. That will happen if either `b` is not the button you think it is or else a different listener is being assigned to the button later in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create dialogs like this, maybe it will work for you.

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
pd.setMessage("Bla bla bla");
pd.show();
//pd.dismiss();
```

Comment: ok.. My layout and class code weren't running together. My mistake. Thanks for the help and problem solving. :)